# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi disconnecting sometimes

Tags: wireless, disconnect

My laptop is disconnecting from wifi at some time, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, please help.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e054]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: You are unlucky. This is Ralink. You can search by this adapter name, but I am not sure there is a good solution for this crappy adapter. I suggest to replace it with something else.

Comment: How can i replace it? How to delete it and install something else? Any examples to replace please?

Comment: I mean physically buy a new adapter and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the drivers?

Or, I think, the simpliest way to physically replace the wireless adapter is to buy something like https://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ausb%20wifi%20adapter (if you don't want to open your laptop and mess around).

Comment: the problem is that i've never had this problem before ( i mean when i had windows 7 ), but linux mint 18, 17.3 and ubuntu 14.04 won't connect

Comment: ok, but what about the drivers? I mean, if it's system-related issue, then it is driver-related or configuration-related problem. I guess that configuration is ok (because the system is newly installed, so default settings should be working).
linux mint and ubuntu are similar in many ways. Maybe try not-so-close-related distro? Puppy, SuSE, Fedora?